# Inequality with Riemann Integrable functions

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let $f,g: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be Riemann Integrable functions so that $f(x) \leq g(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. Then:

$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \ dx \leq \int_{a}^{b} g(x) \ dx$$

---

Proof Attempt:

Let $L = \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \ dx$ and $M = \int_{a}^{b} g(x) \ dx$. Suppose that $L > M$. Let $P$ be a partition of $[a,b]$ and let $T$ be an evaluation set. Then, we know that $g-f$ is Riemann Integrable. So, it is the case that:

$$\exists \delta > 0: ||P|| < \delta \implies |R(g-f,P,T)-(M-L)| < L-M$$

where ||P|| is supposed to denote the norm of the partition and $R(g-f,P,T)$ is supposed to denote the Riemann Sum of $g-f$ over the partition $P$ and evaluation set $T$. The inequality above just amounts to the following;

$$M-L < R(g-f,P,T) < 0$$

whenever $||P|| < \delta$. That implies that:

$$\exists t_i \in T: (g-f)(t_i) < 0$$

$$\exists t_i \in T: g(t_i) < f(t_i)$$

which is a contradiction. $\Box$

Does the proof above work? If it doesn't, then why? How can I fix it?

Comment: Just show that for any partition $P$ that you have $L(f,P) \le L(g,P)$.

Comment: Oh. So my proof doesn’t work? Or is it just unnecessarily long?

Comment: Your proof is fine, just a bit complicated. You know that $R(g-f,P,T) \ge 0$ for any $P,T$ so it follows that $\int (g-f) \ge 0$.

Comment: Oh wow that's so simple